# How to run node.js on SFTP

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, sftp

I have an SFTP connection in WinSCP, and I am able to upload a simple HTML website within it and access that file on the web.
However, I am trying to upload a site that has Node.js, express and MySQL in it.

In my dev environment, I would run `node index.js` and it would serve my node back-end.

How can I run `node index.js` and get the site running through SFTP?

---

[image: My Files on the SFTP]

I've tried running `npm install` via ssh, but got an

> EACCESS error.

I will contact an admin to run this command.
Besides that, what else do I need to run?

Comment: A) Please show the *exact* error text. B) Please don't include screenshots of textual data.

Comment: It's 2023. Isn't there a better deployment method than SFTP? At the *absolute least* why not `rsync`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are mixing things.

**SFTP server** goal is to allow transferring files through a secure way, not running a Node.js backend

You need a server with **Node.js** set up on it to run your Node.js program and maybe something to manage the process like **pm2** or **docker**.

So accessing your server through SSH is a good start, after you need to have the correct rights and access to run the command `npm install` OR `yarn install` depending on your packet manager and then `node app.js`

Take a look also on port allowed, your Node backend should run on a port, and you need to verify this point to (allowed port, proxy if there is etc…)